# How to add css code in onmouseover="hover('')" [JS]

Tags: javascript

I can't adjust my text to be center aligned. I tried to put css code in `onmouseover="hover('')"`  but it doesn't work. What is the get around for this?

Middle circle with id="content" that changes the

tag on hover

```
<div id="circle">
    <p id="content">
        <b><span>Services</span></b>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS Code that I included in the html tag to change content on hover

```
<a href="">
    <div onmouseover="hover('<b>BPO</b>')" onmouseout="hover('<b>Services</b>')" class="scaling" id="circle-2">
        <img src="/static/img/2.png" onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/2b.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/2.png'" style="margin-top:5px;" width=100px/>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div onmouseover="hover('<b>Web Development</b>')" onmouseout="hover('<b>Services</b>')" class="scaling" id="circle-3">
        <img src="/static/img/4.png" onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/4b.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/4.png'" style="margin-top:5px;" width=100px/>
    </div>
</a>
```

JS Code that changes the content of the `<p>` tag

```
function hover(description) {
    console.log(description);
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
}
```

everything is working properly but I can't adjust the text to be in the center regard less of the `<p>` tag length .
The main question is how do i add css code in `onmouseover="hover('')"`

[What i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rv0O.jpg)

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMl1L.jpg)

Comment: You only want the text vertically aligned when the mouse passes over it?

Comment: i want it to be center alinged

Comment: just use css `#content { text-align:center; }`

Comment: no i want it to be included in the 'onmouseover' tag

Comment: Apply the alignment to the element with CSS and you're done. Changing the contents of the element later won't matter, the CSS will still apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code really needed a lot of cleaning up.

You should separate the HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  After doing this, debugging is SO much easier and the code is much simpler to follow.

In addition, you had a great deal of duplication in your code. Again, using CSS and JavaScript can remove that redundancy. For example, styling is done with CSS, not HTML. Tags like `<b>` are deprecated and should no longer be used. By creating CSS styles that incorporate `font-weight:bold` and applying those styles properly, we can get rid of all the `<b>` and `</b>` tags.

```js
// Get all DOM references:
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var cir2 = document.getElementById("circle-2");
var cir3 = document.getElementById("circle-3");

var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

// Attach event handlers:
cir2.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ hover('BPO') });
cir2.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ hover('Services') });

cir3.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ hover('Web Development') });
cir3.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ hover('Services') });

img1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){ changeSource(e,'http://plumseattle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/linkedin-logo.jpg') });
img1.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){ changeSource(e, 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-256.png') });

img2.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){ changeSource(e, 'http://seeklogo.com/images/S/snapchat-logo-2D9C3E7ADA-seeklogo.com.png') });
img2.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){ changeSource(e, 'https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Twitter-icon-vector-400x400.png') });

function hover(description) {
        //console.log(description);
        content.textContent = description;
}

function changeSource(evt, source){
  evt.target.src = source;
}
```

```css
content > span { font-weight: bold;}
.scaling { font-weight:bold; }
.img { margin-top:5px;width:100px; }
```

```html
<div id="circle">
 <p id="content">
    <span>Services</span>
 </p>
</div>

<a href="">
 <div class="scaling" id="circle-2">
   <img id="img1" 
        src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-256.png" 
        class="img">
 </div>
</a>

<a href="">
 <div class="scaling" id="circle-3">
   <img id="img2" 
        src="https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Twitter-icon-vector-400x400.png" 
        class="img">
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if you want some element to listen to "mouseover" event, the best way to go is to use [`EventTarget#addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Just like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/taxigy/fnccduhc/):

```
const node = document.getElementById('hover');

node.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    node.innerText = `Last time mouseover'd at ${new Date()}.`;
});
```

So, now, you need to update children of `#content` and `src` attribute of an image under mouse cursor.

The HTML would look like this:

```
<p id="content">
  Services
</p>

<a href="">
  <div class="scaling" id="circle-2">
    <img src="/static/img/2.png" />
  </div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="scaling" id="circle-3">
    <img src="/static/img/2.png" />
  </div>
</a>
```

while JS code would look like this:

```
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const circle2 = document.getElementById('circle-2');
const circle3 = document.getElementById('circle-3');

circle2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  circle2.children[0].src = '/static/img/2b.png';
  content.innerText = 'BPO';
});

circle2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  circle2.children[0].src = '/static/img/2.png';
  content.innerText = 'Services';
});

circle3.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  circle3.children[0].src = '/static/img/4b.png'
  content.innerText = 'Web Development';
});

circle3.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  circle3.children[0].src = '/static/img/4.png'
  content.innerText = 'Services';
});
```

(check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taxigy/oh208dgr/1/)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and kindness to explain it fully.